# DEF file syntax error in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, winapi, win32-process

I have a vs project which wouldn't compile once I upgraded to visual studio 2012.
Its a win32 dll project and it complains about the def file.
This is the def file,

```
LIBRARY test.dll
VERSION 3.1.4.1
EXPORTS
addNumbers @1
```

and this is the error I get when I compile the project in visual studio 2012 ultimate.

```
Source.def(2): fatal error LNK1118: syntax error in 'VERSION' statement
```

What is confusing me is that, this works perfectly fine with visual studio 2008 & 2010.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> VERSION 3.1.4.1

DEF files are *old*.  Back in ye goode olde days, programmers only ever needed two version numbers, major and minor.  The idea of adding a revision and build number was conjured by a manager, not a programmer.  A *build* number, wtf?

You'll have to settle for `VERSION 3.1`.  And yes, that mistake got silently ignored for a very long time.  Not anymore, the manager finally found out :)

Use a [version resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Link takes only major.minor versions