# LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option '' in VC++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker-errors

I am getting a build error (1>LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option '') while trying to build a project in vc++.

Can someone please help me resolve this?

Comment: This came up as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471337/lnk1117-syntax-error-in-option-version1-0-0 which links to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021950/def-file-syntax-error-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: I had checked the above link before posting the question. As per the instruction, I checked for the version field and it was already empty. The error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

On the Settings
**Project > Settings > Linker**
Removing the "**Version**" entry.

MSDN REF : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wswa0bc6(v=vs.80).aspx

Have a good day.