# LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'LTCG:incremental'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I have a C++ project. Which is based on v120. I retargeted the proj to v140 and I get the below error while building.

LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'LTCG:incremental'

How to fix this?

I tried this https://github.com/DarkstarProject/darkstar/issues/3647 and it did not help
and this as well [LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option '' in VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013570/link-fatal-error-lnk1117-syntax-error-in-option-in-vc)

Comment: Can you  provide vcxproj file and [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?